# Google YouTube Data API version 3, videoEmbeddable error

Tags: search, youtube-api, video-embedding

I am trying out the youTube Data API v3, on this page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Every requests works fine, as long as the **videoEmbeddable** parameter is left blank. As soon as I set it to *true* or *any*, I get a bad request response.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.search",
    "reason": "invalidSearchFilter",
    "message": "Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": ""
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions."
 }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: can you post the code your using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you set videoEmbeddable=true, you MUST also set type=video, otherwise you'll get the "Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions" error.

Comment: What's the situation in .NET v3 youtube api. I keep getting the error even though I set the type parameter to video.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case where you're dealing with the experimental nature of the v3 API (still in beta, technically). If you look earlier on the page, the videoEmbeddable parameter is no longer listed (nor are parameters such as videoSyndicated, publishedBefore/publishedAfter, etc), and so aren't supported in the actual API, even though the API explorer hasn't been updated to match. Hopefully the API explorer will be brought back into sync soon; until then, you could run your own tests following the API reference.